# Is it possible to add some filters when using GeoFirestore for Android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I would like to know if it is possible to add some extra filters (besides radius), when running a GeoQuery like this one:

```
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(lat, lon), rad);
```

For example, let's say I have a collection which stores some invitations to parties. In every invitation document I have the geolocation that tells in which place the party will be and when it will happen.

So I want to make a GeoQuery to retrieve all party invitations in the nearby as long as they are not old invitations for parties that have already been celebrated.

Is it possible to achieve something like that? Thanks in advance.

[GeoFirestore for Android — Realtime location queries with Firebase](https://github.com/suiko1984/geofirestore-android)

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked they said they don’t support compound queries, but you could try using a Boolean to check if the invites are old or seen.

```
   if hasSeen == false { 
            //show invites
   }
```

Something like this is a good wrik